# Make a general function with years from a URL

Tags: r

Let's say I want to make a general function of a URL, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020 . I want the function to act so read_url(year) generates the desired year. How do I build a general URL for this link?

The function should look like this:

```
read_url <- function(year){ 

...
}
```

And below code utilise the function to generate the link:

```
read_url(2015)
```

I assume it has to do with the `rvest` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `paste0`:

```
read_url <- function(year){ 
  paste0("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/",year)
}

read_url(2015)
```

```
[1] "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sprintf` or `paste`

```
read_url <- function(year){
   sprintf('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%d', year)
}
```

-testing

```
> read_url(2015)
[1] "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015"
```